# For cycle strange things

Tags: python

#Hello! I have func for encode int to str and list with 20 different lists of ints (8 in each).
Its all different, but when I run for loop it work strange and output same things only for 1 list in global list( I have same things in differents "for cycle" cases(
Why "for" work strange?

```
#ascii encoder

def ascii_encoder(litter_to_ASCII):

  name = str()
  for part in litter_to_ASCII:

    sign = chr(part)
    messange += sign

  return messange

#list of lists

population = [
[97, 98, 108, 102, 112, 117, 121, 101, 121],
[123, 120, 123, 113, 125, 114, 109, 123, 121],
[122, 119, 97, 122, 105, 98, 95, 123, 110],
[115, 99, 97, 107, 100, 111, 102, 105, 124],
[117, 106, 108, 98, 107, 111, 96, 99, 112],
[116, 124, 114, 113, 99, 104, 104, 99, 108],
[106, 122, 107, 95, 119, 124, 104, 124, 120],
[98, 98, 118, 102, 113, 103, 118, 112, 105],
[114, 111, 124, 102, 115, 123, 106, 110, 101],
[99, 111, 113, 104, 119, 95, 111, 96, 101],
[97, 120, 97, 100, 106, 115, 111, 96, 96],
[104, 114, 113, 100, 125, 101, 104, 123, 115],
[124, 114, 111, 124, 116, 103, 123, 123, 119],
[99, 101, 109, 114, 116, 109, 121, 109, 95],
[124, 101, 97, 115, 103, 104, 105, 120, 95],
[108, 100, 119, 115, 101, 103, 117, 113, 107],
[109, 123, 124, 112, 118, 112, 100, 110, 107],
[105, 123, 103, 121, 103, 96, 99, 124, 108],
[120, 97, 110, 122, 103, 121, 99, 124, 105],
[106, 119, 98, 102, 110, 109, 98, 124, 114]]

#And when I want to encode the list, I have same things

for i in range(len(population)):
  letter = ascii_encoder(population[i])
  letter_list.append(letter)

print(letter_list)


output => all are same0 'jwbfnmb|r'
```

This respekt

Comment: you need to be more precise. "strange" how? What do you expect? What do you get instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:`

Answer (score 0):

There was no problem with the `for` loop. You need to have a variable called `messange = ''` and add the encoded character to it. Earlier, you were adding the same encoded character to `messange` and it was not getting reset to an empty string. Now, at each loop, it will get become an empty string.

Here is how you should do it:

```
def ascii_encoder(litter_to_ASCII):
  messange = '' # This line need to be there to add the character to it for each list.
  for part in litter_to_ASCII:
    sign = chr(part)    
    messange += sign

  return messange

#list of lists

population = [
[97, 98, 108, 102, 112, 117, 121, 101, 121],
[123, 120, 123, 113, 125, 114, 109, 123, 121],
[122, 119, 97, 122, 105, 98, 95, 123, 110],
[115, 99, 97, 107, 100, 111, 102, 105, 124],
[117, 106, 108, 98, 107, 111, 96, 99, 112],
[116, 124, 114, 113, 99, 104, 104, 99, 108],
[106, 122, 107, 95, 119, 124, 104, 124, 120],
[98, 98, 118, 102, 113, 103, 118, 112, 105],
[114, 111, 124, 102, 115, 123, 106, 110, 101],
[99, 111, 113, 104, 119, 95, 111, 96, 101],
[97, 120, 97, 100, 106, 115, 111, 96, 96],
[104, 114, 113, 100, 125, 101, 104, 123, 115],
[124, 114, 111, 124, 116, 103, 123, 123, 119],
[99, 101, 109, 114, 116, 109, 121, 109, 95],
[124, 101, 97, 115, 103, 104, 105, 120, 95],
[108, 100, 119, 115, 101, 103, 117, 113, 107],
[109, 123, 124, 112, 118, 112, 100, 110, 107],
[105, 123, 103, 121, 103, 96, 99, 124, 108],
[120, 97, 110, 122, 103, 121, 99, 124, 105],
[106, 119, 98, 102, 110, 109, 98, 124, 114]]

#And when I want to encode the list, I have same things
letter_list = []
for i in range(len(population)):
  letter = ascii_encoder(population[i])
  letter_list.append(letter)

print(letter_list)
```

Output:

```
['ablfpuyey', '{x{q}rm{y', 'zwazib_{n', 'scakdofi|', 'ujlbko`cp', 't|rqchhcl', 'jzk_w|h|x', 'bbvfqgvpi', 'ro|fs{jne', 'coqhw_o`e', 'axadjso``', 'hrqd}eh{s', '|ro|tg{{w', 'cemrtmym_', '|easghix_', 'ldwseguqk', 'm{|pvpdnk', 'i{gyg`c|l', 'xanzgyc|i', 'jwbfnmb|r']
```